# How to resolve bootstrap 4 frontend issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am following a course to learn Angular and have come across some issue with it. 
I am using the latest version of bootstrap that is bootstrap 4.

I have an issue where my main page is not working as it should be. 
The output shown here is with bootstrap 3.x

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" >Recipe Book</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" >Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Manage</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the updated cdn, or updated css/js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the required `popper.js` and `jQuery` libraries in addition to bootstrap own JavaScript plugins?

Check [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) introduction for more information.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Do we need to add this despite the entire project having the relevant files as I am using Angular and as demonstrated in the video there is no need for the use of these 3rd party plugins and frame works. Which is why i font understand as to why it happens to be so.

Comment: You can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@oyewusioyekunle/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-your-angular-project-angular-8-6379fd6a0f46) to add bootstrap to any component in you angular project.